# How to differentiate name in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a code. Somehow, it only able to pick the last hidden input name field instead of the other one. I also tried use if and else but nothing is displayed. Please advise.

Without the if else cases scenario:

HTML:

```
            <div class="tab-label">
                        <input type="radio" id="ldktech_product_good" name="conditition" value="good" >
                        <input type="hidden" id="ldktech_product_price_good"  name="price" value="7.50">
                        <label for="ldktech_product_good">Good</label>
```

**NOTE:** Please include the charger with your iPad trade-in, or a replacement fee will be deducted from the offer

```
                <div class="tab-label">
                        <input type="radio" id="ldktech_product_flawless" name="conditition" value="flawless" >
                        <input type="hidden" id="ldktech_product_price_flawless"  name="price" value="10">
                        <label for="ldktech_product_flawless">Flawless</label>
```

PHP:

```
$condition = $_POST["conditition"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
echo $price;
echo "<br>";
echo $condition;
```

With the if else scenarios:

HTML Code:

```
            <div class="tab-label">
                        <input type="radio" id="ldktech_product_good" name="conditition" value="good" >
                        <input type="hidden" id="ldktech_product_price_good"  name="price-good" value="7.50">
                        <label for="ldktech_product_good">Good</label>


                <div class="tab-label">
                        <input type="radio" id="ldktech_product_flawless" name="conditition" value="flawless" >
                        <input type="hidden" id="ldktech_product_price_flawless"  name="price-flawless" value="10">
                        <label for="ldktech_product_flawless">Flawless</label>
```

PHP code:

```
$condition = $_POST["conditition"];
if($condition == "good"){
$price = $_POST["price-good"];}
else if ($condition == "flawless"){
$price = $_POST["price-flawless"];}
echo $price;
echo "<br>";
echo $condition;
```

Nothing work. Please advised

Comment: You may need to go through your code and check your spelling since you misspelled "condition" here: $_POST["conditition"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works fine for me. don't know if your form method is post or not or your action url is set to your script url or if your script is on the same page make sure you place it accordingly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>PhpFiddle Initial Code</title>

</head>

<body>
<div style="margin: 30px 10%;">
<h3>My form</h3>
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post">

 <div class="tab-label">
                        <input type="radio" id="ldktech_product_good" name="conditition" value="good" >
                        <input type="hidden" id="ldktech_product_price_good"  name="price-good" value="7.50">
                        <label for="ldktech_product_good">Good</label>


                <div class="tab-label">
                        <input type="radio" id="ldktech_product_flawless" name="conditition" value="flawless" >
                        <input type="hidden" id="ldktech_product_price_flawless"  name="price-flawless" value="10">
                        <label for="ldktech_product_flawless">Flawless</label> <br /><br />
   
 <button id="mysubmit" type="submit">Submit</button><br /><br />

</form>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["conditition"])){
    $condition = $_POST["conditition"];
    if($condition == "good"){
        $price = $_POST["price-good"];
    }
    else if ($condition == "flawless"){
        $price = $_POST["price-flawless"];
    }
echo $price;
echo "<br>";
echo $condition;
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I use POST and send it to another page called "offer.php". At the offer page, I retrieve the information via _POST. However, I tried to echo it but it does not work

Comment: Glad to hear. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're trying to do?

**EDIT:**

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="tab-label">
        <input type="radio" name="condition1" value="good">
        <input type="hidden" name="price1" value="7.50">
        <label for="ldktech_product_good">Good</label>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-label">
        <input type="radio" name="condition2" value="flawless">
        <input type="hidden" name="price2" value="10">
        <label for="ldktech_product_flawless">Flawless</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get records">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['condition1']) && $_POST['condition1'] == "good") {
        echo "You have selected :".$_POST['price1'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
    } else if (isset($_POST['condition2']) && $_POST['condition2'] == "flawless") {
        echo "You have selected :".$_POST['price2'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It does not work. The only thing I can get from the one without the if and else statement is 10. It seems like it does not get the 7.50. Btw, it is two pages code. One in html with form field and POST that send it to the offer.php page. The offer.php page uses the PHP code I posted

Comment: Well if you're working with php code its best to have all your documents as .php instead of one as .html and then another as .php. I'm sure it's no big deal but it would make life a lot easier.

Comment: So what you're trying to do is: <br>If the user selects good, you want it to echo 7.50 else if the user selects flawless you want it to echo 10?

Comment: Tried the updated code. Still not working. Does it because I have two pages? One page is called price_check.html and the other is offer.php. The price check site use Post and action called offer.php. The only value I get is 10 if I put the same name for the hidden form field.

Comment: I'm still having a bit of trouble understanding what you're trying to do, what you want to do, but rename price_check.html to price_check.php and place the php code after the </form> tag in price_check.php, just like above. So instead of calling action="offer.php" you can leave it all in one page and don't have to call action=""